# Server side object located in app.js marked as not exported in my index.ejs file

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I have a problem with referencing an object that is located in my app.js file. I am running my server using express, and for view engine I am using EJS.
The object is created in the app.js file and is then used in my PowerList.ejs file (index file). But when trying to use it, it gets marked as not exported.

**object and function in app.js:**

```
var number = {count: 0};
var profile = {name: 'My name', age: 21, job: 'My profession', hobbies: ['hiking', 'running', 'coding']};
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('PowerList.ejs',{data: profile, number: number}); 
});
```

**objects used in PowerList.ejs:**

```
<section id="history" style="background-color: red; margin: auto; height: 400px; width: 650px; text-align: center; display: none">
    <button id="button">click me</button>
    <p>You have clicked me <%= number.count%> times</p>
</section>
```

What is confusing me is that as you can see in the snippet there is another object called profile which is being used in the same way in my PowerList.ejs file and is not causing any issues.

**profile object usage:**

```
<section id="productivity" style="background-color: bisque; margin: auto; height: 400px; width: 650px; text-align: center; display: none">
    <p><strong>Profile name: </strong> <%= profile.name%></p>
    <p><strong>Age: </strong><%= profile.age%></p>
    <p><strong>Job: </strong><%= profile.job%></p>
    <ul><strong>hobbies:</strong>
        <% profile.hobbies.forEach(function (value) {  %>
            <li><%= value %></li>
        <%});%>
    </ul>
</section>
```

I am also using the number object in a javascript file where it gets incremented on a button click. Here it is also marked as not exported plus i get an error when trying to increment it through clicking a button.

**javascript file:**

```
document.getElementById('button').addEventListener('click', loadNumber);

function loadNumber() {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open('GET', '/', true);
    xhttp.onload = function () {
        if(this.status === 200){
            number.count++;
        }
    };
    xhttp.send();
}
```

error log:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: number is not defined
    at XMLHttpRequest.xhttp.onload (addDelete.js:67)
```

Comment: If you declare `number` in app.js without the `var` keyword, does it become accessible?

Comment: How are you going to have an acces to the object declared on serverside from client-side code?

Comment: You can’t use backend variables on the front end like that.

Comment: problem is clear as day. `res.render('PowerList.ejs',{data: profile, number: ` is incomplete.

Comment: I apologize I did not check the post before posting it and so the line seemed as incomplete, though in the program it is completed as it is supposed to be. I corrected the question.

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio Tried it but nothing changes, still same error.

Comment: @ArtemArkhipov Through ejs template engine.

Comment: just trying to guess, is it possible that `number` is a reserved word? [https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_reserved.asp]

Comment: @CharlieFish Yes you are right, I know it is not the way to go but for now I am still learning the way ejs and nodejs work, so I only do it for practice.

Comment: also, one thing: when you say "I am also using the number object in a javascript file", where exactly is the js file included in your application?

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio Nope it does not show that it is.

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio Are you asking where the javascript file is included?

Comment: @tadej yes, is it declared as <script>...</script> in your ejs file?

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio Yes the javascript file is an external file that is then referenced in the ejs file as such: <script type="text/javascript" src="../addDelete.js"></script> . The file is passed to the client with express.

Comment: @tadej well then, as  Artem Arkhipov and Charlie Fish already pointed out, you are trying to expose a serverside variable to the clientside script; that's not possible. You can pass the value to a client variable in your ejs file like this: `var number = <%= number.count %>;` but you won't be able to update the SERVER SIDE var number from within the client script.

Comment: @GrafiCodeStudio Ok I see now. So server side variables can be displayed on the client but can not be manipulated by the client. Looks like I got it a bit wrong, this web development is still a bit confusing to me haha. Thank you and the rest who responded for your time :). If you want you can post an answer and I will mark it as the correct one.

Answer (score 2):

Your error:

```
var number = {count: 0};
var profile = {name: 'My name', age: 21, job: 'My profession', hobbies: ['hiking', 'running', 'coding']};
app.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('PowerList.ejs',{data: profile, number: 
                                               ^^^^^^^^
});
```

You have two methods to resolve this, or whit the normal:

`number: number`

or you just remove the ":" and it should be good :)

Comment: sorry that was my mistake when copying code i accidentally deleted something and didnt check it before posting. in the program the line is finnished as it is supposed to be:  res.render('PowerList.ejs',{data: profile, number: number});